# Jenkins Pipeline does not detect Android Emulator

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to Checkout,Build and Launch Espresso tests on my emulator before archiving the APK,The problem is that I cannot launch the emulator automatically from Jenkins.However with **the same command** from Windows command line I am able to run the emulator:

Script

```
node{
 // Previous stages and some magic...
 stage('Test') {   
bat "D:\\Tools\\Dev\\sdk\\tools\\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_Marshmallow_API_23"
 }
}
```

Screenshots of [Jenkins Logs and same command on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGc5.png)
 Does anybody have an idea about what can be done to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You shuold try running your command with single quotation marks:

```
bat 'D:\\Tools\\Dev\\sdk\\tools\\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_Marshmallow_API_23'
```

I am also not shure if you need to escape your path.